# WinSock2.h Compilation Errors

Tags: c++, windows-server-2003, visual-studio-2003

I am trying to run a project using Visual studio 2003. But I am getting lot of compilation errors similar to the following.

The errors are pointing to WinSock2.h file. I am copying couple of code snippets from  WinSock2.h file and the corresponding errors

```
typedef struct fd_set {
    u_int fd_count;               /* how many are SET? */
    SOCKET  fd_array[FD_SETSIZE];   /* an array of SOCKETs */
} fd_set;
```

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET
>   2003\Vc7\PlatformSDK\Include\WinSock2.h(114): error C2065: 'fd_set' :
>   undeclared identifier

```
struct sockaddr {
    u_short sa_family;              /* address family */
    char    sa_data[14];            /* up to 14 bytes of direct address */
};
```

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio .NET
>   2003\Vc7\PlatformSDK\Include\WinSock2.h(109): error C2143: syntax
>   error : missing ';' before '{'

The ws2_32.lib file is added to "Configuration properties - Linker - Input - Additional Dependencies". The build configuration platform is win32.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: check if winsock2.h is included prior to any other windows headers (especially windows.h itself). Due to some backward compatibility with broken winsock.h (version 1) include order *does* matter with winsock...

Comment: @Hcorg, There are some windows.h heard files, I changed the header file order/removed etc, but still I am getting the error. Let me try all options..

Comment: @Ullan, do you have a link to a minimal code, to try to solve the problem

Comment: @HocineDJEMAI, Let me see if I can do that. Somebody developed this project long back and I am trying to setup the build environment,

Answer (score 2):

a typical basic Winsock Application with the good order of header files can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```
#ifndef WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#endif

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

The order of including header files is important